# How to condense non-sequential integers?

Tags: r

I'm trying to condense non-sequential numbers to subset haplotype data. I could do it manually, but given that I've got hundreds to do, I'd rather not if there's an alternative

```
class(haplotype1[[1]])
#[1] "integer"

haplotype1[[1]]
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  7  8  9 10 11
```

I want to get `[1:5, 7:11]`, which seems simple, but I haven't found a solution exactly matching my problem

Thanks!

Comment: What does *condense non-sequential numbers to subset haplotype data* mean?

Comment: Hi :-) the 'condense non-sequential numbers' part is really what I'm interested in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `cumsum` to create the sequential groups,

```
tapply(x, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x) != 1)), FUN = function(i)paste(i[1], i[length(i)], sep = ':'))
#    1      2 
#"1:5" "7:11"
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what type of object you want to create. I would just store the start and end values.

```
x <- c(1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11)

starts <- x[!c(FALSE, diff(x) == 1L)]
#[1] 1 7
ends <- x[!c(diff(x) == 1L, FALSE)]
#[1]  5 11

paste(starts, ends, sep = ":")
#[1] "1:5"  "7:11"
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out on the loop! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this ?

```
vec <- c(1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11)

split(vec, cumsum(c(1,diff(vec)>1)))
# $`1`
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# 
# $`2`
# [1]  7  8  9 10 11
```